# child route is deactivated when refreshing page in angular4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular4-router

Hi I am very new to angular, As per my requirment I prepare routing schema like this

```
 {
            path: 'list',
            component: ListComponent,

            children: [
                {
                path: 'view/:id',
                component: ViewRoleComponent,

              },
              {
                path: 'edit/:id',
                component: EditRoleComponent,
                },
              {
                path: 'users/:id',
                component: RoleUsersComponent,

              }]
     }
```

list.html

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4">
<ul>
<li *ngFor = "role of roles">
  <span><label>{{rle.name}}</label>

  <a [routerLink]="['edit', role.id]"   routerLinkActive='active' [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:
                      true}" (click)="setRole(role)"><i>EDit</i></a>
  <a [routerLink]="['view', role.id]"   routerLinkActive='active' [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:
                      true}" (click)="setRole(role)"><i>View</i></a>

</li>
</ul>

</div>
<div class="col-md-8">

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
// view, edit component will load here 
//By default view component loads here first after it's navigaing edit , view using abov links
</div>
</div>
```

**list.component.ts**

```
 export class ListComponent implement OnInit {

    constructor ( private router: Router, private roleService: RoleService,) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.getAllRoles();

    }

    getAllRoles () {
     this.roleService.getAllRoles().subscribe(res => this.sucess(res), err => this.error(err));
    }

     sucess(sucessResponce) {
     this.router.navigate(['cloud/role/list/view' + '' + '/' + sucessResponce[0].id]);
     this.roleService.setRole(sucessResponce[0]);
     }

     setRole (role) {
         this.roleService.setRole(role);
     }


     }
```

**edit.component.ts**

```
 export class EditRoleComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private roleService: RoleService) {}
       ngOnInit () {
         this.roleService.getRole().subscribe(res => {
           console.log(res);// getting responce 
         })
       }


     }
```

**RoleService.ts**
         export class RoleService {

```
      private roleDetails = new BehaviorSubject<any>(0);
      constructor(public http: Http) {}

      getAllRoles(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('url')
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      // ...errors if any
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }


   setRole(role?: any) {
        this.roleDetails.next(role);
    }

    getRole() {
        return this.roleDetails.asObservable();
    }

     }
```

In above componet I am getting all roles from roleservice after getting I am redirecting to view page of o index role, 
 after that if user want to go another view or edit pages then above list html it will navigate, it's working perfectly

Now My Problems are

1) If user is at present edit page url like 'cloud/role/list/edit/6', in this if user refresh the page it redirecting to the o index role view page, 
But my requirment is edit(id-6) link should be active even after refresh the page, By default first only show view page,

2) In list component I am getting all roles, data contain roleId, roleName,status, system---like properties of each role this, I want this properties in my edit component
of cource id i am getting from router, but for ohter things i am useing rxjs behaviour subject, I am getting details of selected role in my edit page,

probelm is after refresh page it's giving 0,

How to solve above two issues, Is there any other way of doing routing for my requirment, What I am following wrong, please guide me

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you pls post your edit component or view component

Comment: @Veena I added edit component, role service in my post, please check it

Comment: all you need is, the current passed 'id' from the url on page refresh, right?

Comment: not only id, i want some more details of each role obj,

Comment: if you want role obj on refresh, then you have to call the getAllRoles() in your edit page too,, otherwise you could not identify  the clicked role, becos on refresh the observable will again get reloaded by the initial value that is, '0' (since it is passed in your list component)

Comment: okay , how to stay edit route only after refresh the page, default i am redirecting to view, i can i stop that after refresh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158288/discussion-between-runali-and-veena-k-suresh).